# Oracle - Query about data in a collection of reference

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am new to Oracle, I had a question which I can not sort out by myself.
I am building a movie database. 
There is my design:
In the movie table, there are many actors, but movie table and actor table should be independent. So I am using a collection of REF link of actors in the movie table. 
There is brief code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE actor_type AS OBJECT (
    name   VARCHAR2(50)  );
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE actor_type_array IS
    VARRAY ( 100 ) OF REF actor_type;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE movie_type AS OBJECT (
    actor        actor_type_array
);
/
CREATE TABLE movie OF movie_type;
/
INSERT INTO movie(actor)
VALUES(
actor_type_array(
(SELECT REF(a) FROM actor a WHERE a.name = 'A'),
(SELECT REF(a) FROM actor a WHERE a.name = 'B')
));
```

When I do my query, I wanted to get the list of actor name of a given movie,
I did in this way:

```
select a.name from movie m, table(m.actor)a;
```

but it said error-a.name is an invalid identifier, but when i replaced it with

```
select * from movie m, table(m.actor)a;
```

I got two reference link to actors. But the specific data inside the actor table didn't reveal.

I have googled it for several days, but found nothing. Can anyone help me with it? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Please tell us if it is Oracle or Mysql (I guess Oracle) and attach create table statement

Comment: yes it's oracle 11g

Comment: create table movie of movie_type;